# Converting RGB value into integers

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an app with a color dropper tool on it using g.CopyFromScreen(screenpoint, Point.Empty, Bmp2.Size) (the dropper tool works currently), once I have the dropper values I want to convert the RBG values into individual integers.

The values that i'm converting are in this format
Color [A=255, R=240, G=240, B=240]
which needs to be in four different integers

My code is giving me odd results and I'm lost now

My code:

```
    Dim text1Conv As String

    text1Conv = TextBox1.Text
    Dim myChars() As Char = text1Conv.ToCharArray()

For Each ch As Char In myChars
        If Char.IsDigit(ch) And Not ch = " " And Not ch = "," And Not count > 2 Then
            color1Conv = color1Conv + ch
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + color1Conv 'test result
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(ch) And Not ch = " " And Not ch = "," And count < 2 And Not count > 5 Then
            color2Conv = color2Conv + ch
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + color2Conv 'test result
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(ch) And Not ch = " " And Not ch = "," And count < 5 And Not count > 8 Then
            color3Conv = color3Conv + ch
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + color3Conv 'test result
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(ch) And Not ch = " " And Not ch = "," And count < 8 And Not count > 11 Then
            color4Conv = color4Conv + ch
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + color4Conv 'test result
            count = count + 1
        End If

    Next
```

results: 225 255 118 112 122
results: 225 255 116 772 721

probably an easy one but I can't see it

Comment: What exactly is the format of Textbox1.Text value? Is it `Color [A=255, R=240, G=240, B=240]`?

Comment: it should look like this 225255118112 as a test result, 4 different integer...textbox1 is just a test output fyi

Comment: And will it always be padded with zeros in case the number will be lower than 100, i.e. will there be always 12 digits?

Comment: Sorry, I meant how should the input look like, the one from which do you need to convert, not to which...

Comment: hmm good question, that actually is something else to think about, maybe my code is completely wrong then. basically the color value can be any color value in the spectrum and needs to be converted into 4 integers A R G B, maybe I can use the space or comma as a marker for the next integer? I wouldn't know where to start again

Comment: input: Color [A=255, R=240, G=240, B=240] output: integer1 = 255 integer2 = 240 integer3 = 240 integer4 = 240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions: 
I used "[A=255, R=241, G=24, B=2]" as a test string and split it into four integers.

```
Dim a as Integer, r as Integer, g as Integer, b as Integer
Dim s as String = "[A=255, R=241, G=24, B=2]"
Dim mc as MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches( s, "(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+", RegexOptions.None )  
Integer.TryParse( mc(0).Groups(1).Value, a )
Integer.TryParse( mc(0).Groups(2).Value, r )
Integer.TryParse( mc(0).Groups(3).Value, g )
Integer.TryParse( mc(0).Groups(4).Value, b )
```

NOTE: it will have no problems with numbers being 1, 2, or any number of digits long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "Color [A=255, R=240, G=240, B=240]"
Dim re As New Regex("Color \[A=(\d+), R=(\d+), G=(\d+), B=(\d+)\]")
Dim m As Match = re.Match(input)
Dim integer1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups(1).Value) '255
Dim integer2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups(2).Value) '240
Dim integer3 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups(3).Value) '240
Dim integer4 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups(4).Value) '240
```